# group by week, get first day of week, pivot by weekday

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to make a query that will show how much of each item/unit combination each customer ordered each week (group by week) while showing the first day the week, and also showing the quantity ordered each day of that week (pivot by weekday). So far i have this, but I'm not sure how to group this by week.

```
SELECT customer_name, item_code, item_desc,  unit, delivery_date, [Monday], [Tuesday], [Wednesday], [Thursday], [Friday], [Saturday], [Sunday]
FROM (
    SELECT customer_name, item_code , item_desc , unit, delivery_date, DATENAME(dw, delivery_date) AS DayWeek, qty
    FROM order_items oi inner join orders on localID = local_order_id
    ) AS ordersItems
    pivot (
        SUM(qty) FOR DayWeek IN ([Monday], [Tuesday], [Wednesday], [Thursday], [Friday], [Saturday], [Sunday])
    ) AS pvt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query groups by customer/item/unit/week# combination. It returns the total number of orders as well as the # of orders broken down by the day of the week. The CASE statement is used along with the SUM function to get the total number of orders for each day of the week

**EDIT**: Revised query to group by Week Starting Date (instead of week # previously)

```
SELECT customer_name, item_code, item_desc, unit, 
CASE SIGN(7-(DATEPART(dw, action)+2))
  WHEN -1 THEN CAST(DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, action)+2), action) AS DATE)
  WHEN 0 THEN CAST(action AS DATE)
  WHEN 1 THEN CAST(DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, action)+2), action) AS DATE)
END Week_Starting_Friday
SUM(qty) Total_Orders, 
SUM(
    CASE DATENAME(dw, delivery_date) WHEN 'Monday' THEN qty ELSE 0 END
) [Monday],
SUM(
    CASE DATENAME(dw, delivery_date) WHEN 'Tuesday' THEN qty ELSE 0 END
) [Tuesday],
SUM(
    CASE DATENAME(dw, delivery_date) WHEN 'Wednesday' THEN qty ELSE 0 END
) [Wednesday],
SUM(
    CASE DATENAME(dw, delivery_date) WHEN 'Thursday' THEN qty ELSE 0 END
) [Thursday],
SUM(
    CASE DATENAME(dw, delivery_date) WHEN 'Friday' THEN qty ELSE 0 END
) [Friday],
SUM(
    CASE DATENAME(dw, delivery_date) WHEN 'Saturday' THEN qty ELSE 0 END
) [Saturday],
SUM(
    CASE DATENAME(dw, delivery_date) WHEN 'Sunday' THEN qty ELSE 0 END
) [Sunday]
FROM order_items oi inner join orders on localID = local_order_id
GROUP BY customer_name, item_code, item_desc, unit, 
CASE SIGN(7-(DATEPART(dw, action)+2))
  WHEN -1 THEN CAST(DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, action)+2), action) AS DATE)
  WHEN 0 THEN CAST(action AS DATE)
  WHEN 1 THEN CAST(DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, action)+2), action) AS DATE)
END
ORDER BY 5, customer_name, item_code, item_desc, unit;
```

**References**:

1. [CASE statement on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)
2. [DATENAME on MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Joseph, this is almost what I need. Instead of the week number, I need to show the first day of that week.

Comment: i've tried dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, delivery_date), 0) and then to group by it but get an error: Column "orders.delivery_date" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: You're welcome @boruchsiper! :-) Try `DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, delivery_date)-1), delivery_date)` for using Sunday's date as the first day of the week.

Comment: Please see revised query above, grouped by the first day of the week.

Comment: Wow man you're awesome. By the way is it possible to get this to work so that the first day of the week is friday? I know, sounds weird, but I might have to do it for the BOSS. Would [DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, delivery_date)-3)] work?

Comment: I noticed that in the comment you wrote DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, delivery_date)-1), delivery_date), but the revised query you wrote: DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, delivery_date)-2), which one is the correct one?

Comment: -1 uses Sunday as the first DOW. -2 uses Monday. So, if you want to begin on Friday, you can use `DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, delivery_date)+1)`.

Comment: @boruchsiper You probably found that the starting date of the week did not always work correctly. I did some more testing and editing the code and have revised the answer above. Sorry about the rework.

Comment: Hey man, requirement changed, so I reposted. You can answer the new question and get the points again. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24461703/group-by-week-get-last-day-of-week-pivot-by-weekday-week-starts-saturday